# Warn users about the 5 minute limit on editing comments

Tags: support, comments

I recently was writing a comment. I was not able to finish it, and had to come back to it later.

I then found there was a 5 minute limit on editing comments. Bummer. It would have been nice to get a warning at the beginning of the edit. Had I known I had a 5 minute limit, I would have written my comment in Notepad first.

Answer (score 8):

You can simply delete your comment and re-enter it.

Comment: Normally I don't like workaround answers, but if the OP was seriously going to write it in notepad ahead of time, this is a perfectly logical way to do it

Comment: I have done this by copying the old comment, deleting it, and pasting it in a new comment, although I do think a warning is in order.